# Get country location by IP (IPv4,IPv6)

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, ipv6, ipv4

I've been testing some code that will allow me to block ads and videos to users from specific countries. This is nothing new and certainly should not be hard to do, however I can't sort it out to work with IPv6 addresses because I don't know how to handle those. I use this database http://db-ip.com/db/ which initially looks like this:

[image]

After converting the two IP column values to binary and moving everything to a new table I have this:

[image]

Here is the test code (when I sort it out, I will use a cfc and stored procedure instead):

```
<!--- manualy change IPs to check if the code works --->
<cfset ipaddress="1.0.127.255">
<cfset ipToArray = listToArray(ipaddress,".")>
<cfset ipBinary= (ipToArray[1] * (256)^3) + (ipToArray[2] * (256)^2) + (ipToArray[3] * 256) + ipToArray[4]>

<cfquery name="getCountry" datasource="mydatabase">
SELECT country
FROM dbip_lookup 
WHERE #ipBinary# >= bin1 AND #ipBinary# <= bin2
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#getCountry.country#</cfoutput>
```

As you can see, nothing too fancy just a simple testing code that works with IPv4 :)
Should I somehow convert IPv6 to binary to make it work? If so, how to do it or is there some other way to achieve the same functionality? I really have no idea where to start :(

**EDIT - STEP BY STEP PROCESS**

create DB table with code from website (addr_type does not exist in csv file so I removed the column to be able to import csv properly)

```
CREATE TABLE `dbip_lookup` (
`ip_start` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
`ip_end` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
`country` char(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ip_start`)
);
```

after the table has been successfully created an attempt to populate the data

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/dbip-country.csv' 
INTO TABLE dbip_lookup2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

fails throwing the following error message "10:07:52    LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/dbip-country.csv'  INTO TABLE dbip_lookup2  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'ip_end' at row 158131   19.641 sec
" 158131 line is where IPv6 addresses start.

after modifying both varbinary columns to (50) mysql successfully created and populated the table with the above code.

[image]

your a bit simplified cfm code (it does not work either way)

```
<cfset InetAddress = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress")>
<cfset addrStart = InetAddress.getByName("2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344").getAddress()>

<!--- for MySQL.  Use TOP 1 for SQL Server --->
<cfquery name="qResult">
select country from dbip_lookup2
where ip_start <= "#addrStart#"
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#qResult.country#</cfoutput>
```

triggers custom error handler:

[image]

line 43 is where WHERE clause starts

Comment: http://db-ip.com/db/ does support IPv6, there are plenty of those in the DB :)

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the [sample look up code](http://db-ip.com/db/#php) in PHP, one can port over the logic to something like this for looking up IPv6 in CF, without converting into a new table:

```
<cfset InetAddress = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress")>
<cfset addrStart = 
  InetAddress.getByName("2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344").getAddress()>

<!--- for MySQL.  Use TOP 1 for SQL Server --->
<cfquery name="qResult">
  select * from dbip_lookup
  where addr_type = 'ipv6' and 
    ip_start <= <cfqueryparam value="#addrStart#" type="CF_SQL_VARBINARY">
    order by ip_start desc limit 1
</cfquery>
```

I haven't tried this though, hope you can get it working.

**EDIT**

you must use `<cfqueryparam>` for `addrStart` because CF cannot convert a binary array into a string with `##` and send over as SQL.  If that doesn't work still, then consider converting into a hex using `BinaryEncode()`.

Comment: dont know how to get country info based on IPv4 unless two additional columns are assigned!? how to count within range?

Comment: I've also checked you code and got "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings" this is probably because I've changed varbinary to varchar...the code for creating table on the website does not work!

Comment: just use the DB as is, don't change it and the look up code should work as expected.  If you use MSSQL, use that ZORAN DB-IP Importer at http://db-ip.com/db/#external

Comment: You can add additional logic to detect if the IP is v4 or v6, and use the correct `addr_type` accordingly

Comment: yes I will add that later as well as use cfc and storedprocedure insted of the testing code, however need to get it work. I use mysql and the code does not work!

Comment: there are several bugs here, first addr_type is missing from DB (when remove it I can create table with the code from the website) though when I try to import csv to mysql I got the fallowing error msg "Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'ip_end' at row 158131", thats where IPv6 addresses start

Comment: yes and mysql throws an error I mentioned above (Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'ip_end' at row 158131). also I do not see how this will work with IPv4 if sorted out!?

Comment: maybe you should contact http://db-ip.com/contact/ for support.  `varbinary(16)` should work though.

Comment: i'll try that. also as I can see it wont work with IPv4 because the two additional columns with calculated range are needed to get the result.

Comment: Please open up the PHP code and look.  You don't need any additional calculated columns.  Just code your query differently and it'll work.

Comment: whatever I try it simply doesnot work (even with this #ToString(addrStart)#), anyway will make it work partially with IPv4 only

Comment: what doesn't work? mySQL? CF? please update your question with the actual error message / stack trace.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things to get (addrStart) to desirable format but can not sort it out :(

Comment: I tried everything you said and everything I could think of, but also spent hours and hours reading on this topic, which by the way did not get me any closer to finding the solution. Now I am pretty much desperate :(( do you have any other suggestion, any other way to try to sort it out?

Comment: It seems like the geo location DB is not very good.  First it doesn't seem to work as documented (misnamed column, or different DB structure).  Second, it only provided PHP sample code without any other API documentation.  So if it's possible, try looking elsewhere.  There are also API services that does it for you without hosting the DB yourself, such as: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2021-Geocoding-IP-Addresses-For-Free-Using-IPInfoDB-And-ColdFusion.htm or http://dvolvr.davidwaterston.com/2012/07/08/geolocating-ip-addresses-for-free-using-geoplugin-net-and-coldfusion/

Comment: ok I see that :) anyway I do not want to rely on a web service!! I can make this or maxmind DB work with IPv4 only with ease and that's what I am gonna do.